# What is the meaning of testb instruction?

Tags: gdb

Can any one tell me the meaning of the following:

```
gdb> disas 0x080ed5af 

0x080ed5ac <func1+205>:        mov    0x8(%eax),%eax

0x080ed5af <func1+208>:        testb  $0x10,0x8(%eax)

0x080ed5b3 <func1+212>:        jne    0x80ed604 <dapriv_disk_op+293>

0x080ed5b5 <func1+214>:        mov    %edi,(%esp)
```

What is the meaning of `testb  $0x10,0x8(%eax)`?

Answer (score 14):

It performs a bitwise AND of the two operands (`0x10` AND `0x8(%eax)` (this is, the value of the byte located at the address pointed to by `%eax` + 0x8). Neither of the operands is altered, however, the instruction alters the flags, most importantly the ZF flag to either 1 if the result of the AND is zero, or 0 otherwise. The following `jne` performs a jump if ZF is equal to 0.

Comment: Thanks sid. One more thing if eax register has null value then what will hppen? gdb> info registers                        eax            0x0      0
ecx            0x1      1

Comment: Is it will create a panic

Comment: The CPU will trap if nothing is mapped into virtual memory at NULL (generally the case on modern systems).  Depending on what the OS trap handler does, behavior that follows will vary.  Usually a trap created by an ordinary userspace program will cause the program to exit with a SIGSEGV on POSIX-like systems.  But faulting kernel mode code probably causes a panic.